# Aggregate User-Agent String Parsing in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have log files stored as json in MongoDB. One of the fields is a user-agent string eg

```
"Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; U; CPU OS 3_2_1 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/531.21.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/7B405".
```

Is there an easy way to perform aggregates across browser, device, platform etc. Usually I would extract the string and use a parser (eg https://github.com/faisalman/ua-parser-js ) but I also want to perform aggregate counts (eg how many users use chrome?). I don't want to extract each json document, parse the user-agent and then store it in a separate table. I'd like to be able to run the aggregate query across a string field in MongoDB.

Thanks

Comment: You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful, too, despite its harsh title. tl;dr: example docs and expected output surely would help.

Comment: Not much wrong with the question if you know what a user-agent string is. I have added an example user-agent string.

Comment: Well, it is. What is the data you expect? What is your data stored like? What kind of aggregations do you want to do _exactly_? Instead of trying to be a smarty pant, improving the question with details seems to be much more efficient for me. You might even get a complete solution.

Comment: I was updating the question as you were typing your previous comment.